# CSS Drop-Down Menu Not Working in IE9

Tags: css, drop-down-menu, internet-explorer-9

UPDATE: I am using Yahoo's SiteBuilder software and, since I suspect the problem may have to do with the doctype header, I did a Google search on that for SiteBuilder. Someone in another forum suggested adding the following to the questioner's website

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
```

I tried adding that to the top of my page's HTML. The drop-down menu worked in IE9, but in both IE and Firefox the text, log-in box, etc. were all jammed in the upper left corner of the screen. So it would appear to be something in the Doctype, but there's something else going on that's shifting everything out of place. Any suggestions based on this development?

Thank you!

I will begin by stating up front that I am a complete newbie when it comes to this stuff. So please forgive me if I ask basic questions or need overly-explicit instructions.

Basically, I want to add a drop-down navigation menu to my new website. I found code for one online and through some trial and error worked out how to make it my own. Everything seemed fine until I tested it on IE9. When I hover the pointer over it, the drop-down doesn't drop down. It works fine in Firefox (my primary browser) and a friend confirmed it worked on Chrome.

Some Google searches later, I can see this is a fairly common problem. I've tried to find a workable solution, but either the suggested fixes didn't work or I don't really understand what they're talking about. As I said, I am a newbie struggling to understand this new language.

Here is the site: http://gardenstatelegacy.com/GSL2_Test_Home.html

This is a work in progress. The "Subscribe" link works on both Firefox and IE9. The "Resources" tab should have the drop-down menu. The only link that is currently working in that drop-down list is the "Consultant Directory." I tried it using the "compatibility view" option in IE9, but it did not do anything.

I am copying and pasting the code I am using below. If anyone can see why this isn't compatible with IE, please let me know and how I can fix it. Again, I'm new to this, so please make it simple. Thank you in advance for any help!

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>   
  <head> 
   <style type="text/css">      
        body {
            padding: 0; 
            margin: 0;
        }

        #wrap   {
            width: 100%;
            height: 50px; 
            margin: 0; 
            z-index: 99;
            position: relative;
            background-color: #660000;
        }

        .navbar {
            height: 50px;
            padding: 0;
            margin: 0;
            position: absolute;
            border-right: 1px solid #660000;
        }

        .navbar li {
            height: 50px;
            width: 142px; 
            float: left; 
            text-align: center; 
            list-style: none; 
            font: normal bold 12px/1.2em Arial, Verdana, Helvetica;  
            padding: 0;
            margin: 0;
            background-color: #660000;                  
        }

        .navbar a {                         
            padding: 18px 0; 
            border-left: 1px solid #C4BD97;
            border-right: 1px solid #C4BD97;
            text-decoration: none;
            color: white;
            display: block;
        }

        .navbar li:hover, a:hover {
            background-color: #660000;
        }

        .navbar li ul {
            display: none;
            height: 50px;                                   
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;                             
        }

        .navbar li:hover ul {
            display: block;                                 
        }

        .navbar li ul li {
            background-color: #660000;
        }

        .navbar li ul li a {
            border-left: 1px solid #C4BD97; 
            border-right: 1px solid #C4BD97; 
            border-top: 1px solid #C4BD97; 
            border-bottom: 1px solid #C4BD97; 
        }

        .navbar li ul li a:hover {
            background-color: #660000;
        }
    </style>                            
 </head>
 <body>
   <div id="wrap">
        <ul class="navbar">
            <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Sample Issue</a></li>
            <li><a href="http://gardenstatelegacy.com/Subscribe.html">Subscribe</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Resources</a>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#">History Sites/Groups</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Speakers Bureau</a></li>
                    <li><a href="http://gardenstatelegacy.com/Professional_Directory.html">Consultant Directory</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Links</a></li>
                </ul>         
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">About GSL</a>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#" >Mission Statement</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Who We Are</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">News</a></li>
                </ul>         
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">GSL Store</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Advertise</a></li>
        </ul>
   </div>
 </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't have a solution for you, but I confirmed that it does not work in IE10 but does work in FireFox 19 (both on the PC).

One thing you may want to check is the doctype as that's been known to cause cross-browser issues when it comes to CSS.  Try setting that and see if that helps.

Sorry I couldn't be more help.

Comment: Thanks Dave. How would I do that? I presume you mean the <!DOCTYPE html> line at the top? Can you suggest a replacement? Hey, I warned I was a newbie! :)

Comment: Actually the code you pasted in your question is definitely not the code being shown in the page. IE is rendering in quirks mode. The source in IE shows no doctype at all.

Comment: I should probably add the following details. I am using Yahoo's SiteBuilder. The drop-down menu is created by copying the code for the menu and pasting it into an html frame. The code in my question is from that html frame and defines the menu. The code for the menu appears further down. Where would the doctype be? Thanks!

Comment: And I gotta ask...what's "quirks mode"? Sorry, like I said, I am a newbie!

Comment: Yeah - you would do it as part of the HTML tag.  Here are some examples.  (I'm not sure off of the top of my head which one would be best for you, so you'll have to read up and play with it a bit.)  http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_doctype.asp

Comment: Thanks Dave. I tried all of the doctype suggestions and all had the same effect - the drop down menu worked in both Firefox and IE9, but all the elements I had placed in SiteBuilder were shoved into the upper left corner of the screen! I need to be able to modify the site on a regular basis in SiteBuilder, so having to mess with the code to move stuff around is not an option. Any clue as to why it is making my life hell?

Comment: Well, it's SiteBuilder :)  I like to try to fix problems instead of finding new solutions, but in my experience SiteBuilder is more trouble than it's worth.  Is switching to WordPress an option?

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue and I remember I messed around with the z-index (increased the value) and removing the "float:left".

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. If I understand correctly, the z-index tells what elements are in front of what. I don't think that's it because the drop-down part is visible in Firefox and Chrome. I took out the "float:left" and it seems to have just put the links on top of one another instead of along the width. I think Dave may have been onto something. It seems to be a compatibility issue.

Comment: it is a quirk in ie9, but css coding is all about handling the quirks (unfortunately).  IE is notorious for behaving different (even between versions).  Although, it seems to be getting better.

Comment: correct. The z-index controls what element is displayed in front of what.  The higher the z-index, the element will be brought to the front.  I had a similar issue, but the menu list was not displaying over a table.  You can also play around with removing the "absolute" setting. Sorry to be non-specific, but I don't have access to my code now.